# ListView Example with Simple Java Objects for Items

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new to Android programming.  I can get simple ListViews to work in which I use an ArrayList of strings.  I want to take a step upward in complexity and have my ListView be composed of simple Java objects like this:

```
class myItem {
    public String name;
    public Integer price;
    public Integer weight;
}
```

The ListView only needs to display the name in the above object.  It doesn't have to have multiple icons, or multiple clickable actions for each item.

But I don't know where to start.  All of the examples I see on the WWW are much more complicated and require me to learn things that have nothing to do with this (like a database).  Or each ListView items is displayed with multiple views like text and images and icons etc. and each is clickable for a different action.  I don't need any of that, and I'm getting bogged down reading about unneeded features in order to get those examples to work.

Does anyone have an example of a simple ListView that contains simple Java objects (like the one above)?

Comment: I don't use database.

Comment: Do you have a lot of names? where do you store them? If you have lots of them then consider database and you can use simple cursor adapter.

Comment: I don't have any names.  I don't need the database.  I don't want to have to read and learn about how to use a database.  That's what I'm trying to say.  I don't want to spend a week learning how to use lots of new features that I don't need and will never need.

Comment: I mean items, any way use @CommonsWare solution.

Comment: What is @CommonsWare solution?  Nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know where to start.

Implement a `public String toString()` method on `myItem`. Then create an `ArrayList<myItem>` and use that instead of `ArrayList<String>`, populate that list with suitable `myItem` instances, and put the list into an `ArrayAdapter<myItem>` instead of an `ArrayAdapter<String>`. No other changes should be required -- whatever layout you are using for an `ArrayAdapter<String>` will work with your `ArrayAdapter<myItem>`.

In case you are new to Java, `toString()` is the standard Java method for returning a `String` representation of an object. The default behavior of `ArrayAdapter` is to call `toString()` on the object for the given list position and use that to fill in the row.

Comment: Okay.  Sounds too easy.  I'm trying this.